# Cannot start android emulator with AMD Ryzen 2600, SMV, Hyper-v and windows hyperv platform enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v, amd-processor

I can't start android emulator and I don't why, because I tried all solutions found here and in other sites, but nothing.

- I have a CPU AMD Ryzen 2600
- MB ASrock B450 gaming k4
- Android Studio 3.4.1
- Bios MB 3.30 (last one)
- SMV enabled
- Windows 10 build 1903 18362.239
- Hyper-v enabled
- Windows Hyper-v Playform enabled

I tried also disable one feature but nothing changed, and the strange thing is that VirtualBox start without problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you say it doesn't start, you don't get the window popup at all, or the window appears but then instantly crashes? It might be worthwhile checking the application logs in the Windows event viewer for any info

Comment: Nope, I can't create an android virtual space